# Turn a dictionary into two lists, one for keys and the other for values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I read in a object of type `collections.defaultdict` from a file using `pickle.load`. It has a numerical value for each string key. It seems to be just like an object of type `dict`, or I might be wrong.

I would like to create two lists out of the object, one list consisting all the keys, and the other list all the values. How can I do that for an object of type `dict`? How can I do that for an object of type `collections.defaultdict`?

For example, from an object of type `dict`

```
tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
```

I would like to create two lists `['jack', 'sape']` and `[4098, 4139]`.

Thanks!!

Comment: same order, or is the order of the two lists irrelevant?

Answer (score 36):

You can use in Python 2.x:

```
keys = tel.keys()
values = tel.values()
```

Or something funky like:

```
(keys,values) = zip(*tel.iteritems())
```

And in Python 3.x:

```
keys = list(tel.keys())
values = list(tel.values())
(keys,values) = zip(*tel.items())
```

(as in 3.x, keys(), values() and items() return iterators)

Comment: why not just `list(tel.iterkeys())` ? +1 all the same I didnt know they got rid of the other one in py3

Comment: yeah, good point. although list(tel.iterkeys()) becomes just tel.keys().

Comment: This is what I want to do, but I get somehow paranoid about keys() and values() etc not having guaranteed order in dicts. However I guess they must always be guaranteed to match correctly? Assuming the dict is not modified in between calls? I guess the one using .items() is especially safe.

Answer (score 14):

In one step (Python 2.x):

```
keys, values = zip(*tel.iteritems())
```

Or in Python 3.x:

```
keys, values = zip(*tel.items())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
keys = my_dict.keys()
vals = my_dict.values()
keys,values = zip(*my_dict.items())
```

Comment: O i didnt know that went away in py3

Comment: sorry tired... iterkeys() in 2.x = keys() in 3.x

Answer (score 3):

```
k = tel.keys() # a list of the dict keys
v = tel.values() # a list of the dict values
```

Or

```
k, v = [], []
for key, value in tel.items():
    k.append(key)
    v.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key = []
value = []
for i,j in tel.iteritems():
    key.append(i)
    value.append(j)


 key
['sape', 'jack']
value
[4139, 4098]
```

This **iteritems** should do the trick:)